# How to perform custom client authentication using certificate on Jetty-9?

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, jetty-9

I have a SAAS which services multiple customers and I want to be able to use client certificate to authenticate the different customers (different certificate for different customers). My services runs on Jetty 9 (not embedded). How do I do that?

If I use `<auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>` I am also required to provide the `LoginService` in the Jetty configuration, but that doesn't make sense to me because I need to be able to write the authentication code based on the certificate.

I want to stress that I need to do the client authentication per customers, so this needs to be on the application level and not the Jetty level using the SSL setup.

Comment: Any luck on this? I am looking for similar case

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.6.v20141205/configuring-security-authentication.html), it looks like the LoginService is what you should use on the application level for the authorisation step.